# How using lambda to make std::invoke lazy evaluation?

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, c++17, c++20

C++11 introduces [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) allow us to easier implement *lazy evaluation* in C++, so I wonder it is possible to make `std::invoke` in such manner?

According to cppreference, [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is implement with:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
  noexcept(...)
{
    return detail::INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

We can see a lot of *perfect forwarding* here, and I want make this *lazy evaluation*. Here is my implementation:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
constexpr auto delay_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return [&]() -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

And it passed my test in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yGLbgz1CKC5SjyUX). Since this lambda is capturing by reference, I think there is a dangling reference issue in such  manner, so I try the second implementation with capturing by value:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
constexpr auto delay_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return [=]() mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::invoke(static_cast<F&&>(f), static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    };
}
```

and it also passed my test. 
Am I right? Do you have nicer implementation or other good solution? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you have nicer implementation or other good solution?

Your two examples either capture *everything* by reference (which is bad because dangling, especially in a use-case like this) or *copy everything* (which is less bad than the other one, but simply inefficient since some of the arguments might be rvalues). What you want to do is forward the whole pack. However, in C++17, capturing a pack "by forward" was very tedious. Thankfully, in C++20, thanks to [P0780](https://wg21.link/p0780), this will become a lot easier. The motivating example in that paper was very close to your example.

The C++17 version of capturing by forward requires a `tuple` (or something similar):

```
template <typename... Args>
auto delay_invoke(Args&&... args) {
    return [tup=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]() mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::apply([](auto&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
            return std::invoke(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
        }, tup);
    };
}
```

The C++20 version is much more straightforward:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto delay_invoke(Args&&... args) {
    return [...args=std::forward<Args>(args)]() mutable -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: @康桓瑋 You don't have two parameters, you have >= 1 parameters. `[=]` copies all of them. It doesn't matter if they're rvalues, `[=]` is a copy, never a move.